# Should 'Why doesn't <x> language have <y>?' be considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, on-topic

It may be tempting to ask questions about why your favorite languages is missing a specific useful feature. I have seen (and posted) such questions on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Their reception is mixed. I can see how one could argue that they are opinion-based, or not particularly constructive (The answer is just *'That's the way it is.'*). However, sometimes there is a particular, insightful reason to not implement a certain feature for a certain language.

What should be the guidelines with regards to *'Why doesn't <x> language have <y> feature?'* type questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Allow with edits

Allow them, but edit the question to be phrased constructively. "Why doesn't C++ have sum types?" is likely to devolve into opinion-based answers, but with some minor modification, any of the following extremely similar questions seem more objective and thought-provoking:

- What would it take to add sum types to C++20?
- Could a C++-like language support sum types?
- How would adding sum types to C++ change the existing type system?

Comment: wait- doesn't c++ already support sum types since v17 with `std::variant`? and you could do tagged unions manually before that with `union`.

Comment: @starball Debatable. I don't consider those solutions satisfactory. `std::variant` is, at best, the visitor pattern supplied by the standard library. No syntax support, no proper pattern matching, no interaction with the type system. As implemented, it could've been a library feature (and, in fact, it was for a long time in Boost).

Comment: I've heard [Herb and others are working on `is` and pattern matching](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2392r0.pdf) (and other things (cppfront)). Not sure how that's going along.

Answer (score 0):

So long as they can be answered with facts, allow them.